# Kex error when trying to ssh from raspberri pi to ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, raspbian

I have a VPS server running Ubuntu 20.04 and OpenSSH 8.2p1, and a Raspberry Pi 3 running Debian Buster and OpenSSH 7.9p1.

I can ssh into the VPS fine from my desktop, but when I try from my Pi, I get a Kex error.

```
Sep 12 18:41:30 myhost sshd[3197]: Unable to negotiate with xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 64952: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1 [preauth]
```

I hunted around and found [several](https://superuser.com/questions/868998/how-can-i-find-a-list-of-macs-ciphers-and-kexalgorithms-that-my-openssh-client/1219759#1219759) [answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340844/how-to-enable-diffie-hellman-group1-sha1-key-exchange-on-debian-8-0#340853) to this already, however none of the methods worked for me, and regardless seem to indicate that the problem is that the server does not support modern Kex algorithms, which I didn't think would be the case here.

Here's the output of `ssh -Q kex` on both the VPS and the Pi:

```
 VPS                                    | Pi
----------------------------------------|----------------------------
diffie-hellman-group1-sha1              | diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
diffie-hellman-group14-sha1             | diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
diffie-hellman-group14-sha256           | diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
diffie-hellman-group16-sha512           | diffie-hellman-group16-sha512
diffie-hellman-group18-sha512           | diffie-hellman-group18-sha512
diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1      | diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256    | diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
ecdh-sha2-nistp256                      | ecdh-sha2-nistp256
ecdh-sha2-nistp384                      | ecdh-sha2-nistp384
ecdh-sha2-nistp521                      | ecdh-sha2-nistp512
curve25519-sha256                       | curve25519-sha256
curve25519-sha256@libssh.org            | curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
sntrup4591761x25519-sha512@tinyssh.org  |
```

And here's the contents of my `.ssh/config` file on the Pi:

```
IdentitiesOnly yes

Host myhost
    HostName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    User myuser
    Port 22
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_myhost
```

Any help debugging this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm put myself on a wild goose chase for no reason - the problem here was that I miss-typed my VPS server's IP address by one character in the `.ssh/config` file.

Ouch.