# Unable to connect to remote ssh server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openssh

I have a Linux server running Ubuntu 22.04., and I am able to connect to it via ssh on LAN (`ssh user@192.168.X.XX`), but I am unable to connect via WAN. So if I try to run `ssh -p 22 user@<router ext.ip>`, I always get the following error code (I have already set up port forwarding):

```
  Unable to negotiate with <IP address> port 22: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

But, since my router does not have constant IP address, I have set up dynamic DNS and even if I try `ssh -p 22 user@XXXX.ddns.net`, I am still getting the same error code.

**What I have already tried**

1. [this answer from Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/340853/533341)
   But then I am getting this error:

```
Unable to negotiate with <IP address> port 22: no matching cipher found. Their offer: 
3des-cbc
```

And If I try to force `3des-cbc` with `ssh -c 3des-cbc user@XXX.ddns.net`, then I, once
again, get this error:

```
Unable to negotiate with <IP address> port 22: no matching key exchange method found. 
Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

2. Update `~/.ssh/config`  and `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` with

```
Host XX.XX.XX.XX
    Ciphers 3des-cbc
    KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

However, that is also not giving any result (the same error msg)
3. Update / Reinstall / Stop - Start service / Disable - Enable service
This is also not working.

**NOTE:** I am using `openssh-server`, version `(1:8.9p1-3)`.

What should I do now?

Comment: "*that is also not giving any result (the same error msg)*" -- which "same error"?  You've posted two different errors.

Comment: 1. You're connecting to the wrong external address, or 2. You're using different clients for the internal and external connections attempt that are configured differently, or 3. Your router is offering port 22 for a different purpose overriding your port forward

Comment: If you _catefully_ disable the ssh service, what happens when you try to connect (a) from your LAN, (b) remotely?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.